# Does the definition of "originate" allow it to apply to instances that happened independently of the first occurrence?

Tags: word-usage

The expression "smoke test" originated in the electronics field.
When a circuit board is ready to be tested, the first thing one does it turn on the power.
If it immediately produces smoke, it's failed the "smoke test".
If it doesn't, then the normal testing procedures can be performed.

But long before that, the expression originated in plumbing.
To determine if there was a leak in a sewage system, strong smelling smoke would be forced into into it, and if smoke leaks out anywhere, it's failed the "smoke test".

The above provides an example, not the point of this question, which is about the word "originate".

Assuming that each of these very similar uses was created independently (e.g. there's no reason to think that an electronics engineer would have known about plumbing techniques from long ago), is it appropriate to say that "smoke test" originated in the electronics field, or can things originate only once?

Suppose you create something, and then years later I create the same thing without any knowledge of what you had done.
It obviously originated from you, but did it also originate from me?

**Does the definition of "originate" allow it to apply to instances of something that happened independently of the first occurrence?**

Comment: Derived from a [SE Skeptics question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53899/does-the-source-of-the-phrase-smoke-test-come-from-electronic-hardware-testing).

Comment: "Can things originate only once?" Things can be invented or discovered independently, by different people. Sometimes because of the state of science at the time, at other times because science wasn't ready for the information: wrong person, place and time.

Comment: It's common for the meaning of words to gradually shift or expand, just as it's common for inventions to develop little by little such that it's impossible to say who invented e.g. cinema or the steam engine.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the question is about the use of the word "originate", not about the actual process of originating things. It means "*to bring into existence, give rise or origin to*", so does it make sense that something could be brought into existence more than once?

Comment: @StuartF, yes, but the question is about the proper use of the word "originate". Can one say something originated in one place at one time and also that it originated somewhere else at a different time?

Comment: I suupose then it's a similar argument to "Is there only one universe?" and the use of 'unique'.

Comment: It seems to me obvious that the phrase in your example has two independent origins and two initially distinct uses; as they both got extended metaphorically, the patterns of usage that developed out of them merged. Why do you doubt that one can say that?

Comment: @jsw29, I'm asking whether the definition of "originate" allows the possibility of applying to instances beyond the first.

Comment: Why would you want to say 'X originated in Y and Z' rather than 'X has two independent origins: Y and Z'? While I don't see why you would be disallowed from saying the former, the latter is much clearer.

Comment: @jsw29, I wouldn't.  But if someone writes "originated" in reference to a second instance, is it wrong?  It felt wrong to me, but that doesn't mean it is, and I simply wanted to confirm one way or the other. (Somehow I mistakenly thought this was a simple question.)

Answer (score 1):

To say that X originated in Y, means that Y is X's origin. It is perfectly possible for something to have two or more independent origins, if it is a result of the merger of the developments that were initially separate. It is therefore possible for X to originate in Y and Z. Saying

> X originated in Y and Z

is, however, undesirable, because it is ambiguous between Y and Z being two independent origins of X, and the combination of Y and Z being one origin. It is much better to express the idea by saying:

> X has two independent origins: Y and Z.

Also, if Y and Z are two independent origins of Z, it would be misleading to say

> X originated in Y

because such formulations conversationally implicate that Y is the one and only origin of X.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the definition of "originate" allow it to apply to instances of something that happened independently of the first occurrence?

No. Not on it's own. It requires qualification and explanation - you are attempting to describe two separate things that share a name:

> ***In the electronics industry**, the phrase the smoke test originated from turning on the power. If the item immediately produced smoke, its failed the "smoke test."*

You could stop at this point, or continue...

> *The phrase "smoke test" had been earlier used in an unrelated context, by the drainage industry where dense smoke was used to test for leaks.*

With the qualification "originate" is normal.

I am reminded of the word "nyctograph": one was invented and named by Lewis Carroll (Charles Dodgson) and was a device for writing in the dark; the other was a early system of signalling at sea and at night. The item described by same word had different origins.